# is there a time between .get() and .then()

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following method

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('123')
.get(GetOptions(source: Source.server).then((value){
      if(if We Have internet){
        print('true');
      }else{
        print('false');
      }
    });
```

Now lets say we have two times:

1. the first time is `.get()`
2. the second time is after `then()`

Lets say there was internet access with first time so `.get()` will successful performed.

And when `then()` called internet is unavailable. Is there a possibility of this happening?

Note : i already know that i can use `.catchError()` to chick what the error type is or `transection` To ensure everything is done with the same process .

i only want to know As my question is asked yes or no .

I want to know if there is enough time or (possibility) for a change in the network between `.get()` and `then()` Or is this impossible to happen ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you instruct the `get` call to get the data from the server, your `then()` will only be called if the SDK was able to get the data from the server.

If there *is* a connection to the server, either your `then` will be called with the data or `catch` will be called in case of an error.

There is a time difference between when you call `get()` and when that in turn calls `then`, as that is the time it takes to retrieve the data from the server.